# Vuetify <v-list-item-group> v-model mutliple selecting doesnt work

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

```js
<v-list shaped>
  <v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-list shaped>
      <v-list-item-group
          v-model="selectedItem"
          multiple
      >
        <template v-for="(item, i) in items">
          <v-list-item
              :value="item"
          >
            <v-list-item-title>{{item.text}}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </template>
      </v-list-item-group>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
```

```js
data: () => ({
    selectedItem: 0,
    drawer: null,
    items: [
      { icon: 'fas fa-home', text: 'Dashboard', route: '/home' },
      { icon: 'fas fa-money-check-alt', text: 'Invoices', route: '/invoices' },
      { icon: 'fas fa-dolly', text: 'Partners', route: '/partners' },
      { icon: 'fas fa-exchange-alt', text: 'Items', route: '/items' },
    ],
  }),
```

Very simple code in vuetify (2.6.1),multiple selecting doesnt work,
I can't preselect first item to be selected too. Its probably related to v-list-item-group component.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 mistakes in your code:

- when you are using **multiple** prop, a **selectedItem** should be *an array*;
- when you are applying `:value="item"`, your **selectedItem** array should contain the whole object instead of its index.

So your code should be:

```
...
<v-list-item-group
  v-model="selectedItem"
  multiple
>
  <template v-for="(item, i) in items">
    <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-title>{{item.text}}</v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item>
  </template>
</v-list-item-group>
...
data: () => ({
  items: [
    ...
  ],
  selectedItem: [0],
}),
...
```

Comment: I have tried copy pasted your snippet as you suggest but now my rows are missing class **v-list-item--active**,
so after click nothing is selected at all. https://ibb.co/wrgG5wB

Comment: @Coolman, It works fine [at CodePen sandbox](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/qBPOedN). Possibly there are any other problems in your template. Check your browser console for errors or warnings